# How to execute the php script that stored in database

Tags: php

The following string (which comes from database) is stored as a variable,

```
str = "if($me == 1) 
{
 return array(9=>true,10=>true,11=>true)
} 
else 
 {
  return  array(9=>false,10=>false,11=>false)
 }"
```

Since the script is dynamic... so need to find output from this by passing a variable. can anyone help me how to do this.

Comment: I have to ask. Why are you storing PHP in the database?

Comment: I don't understand why it would need to come from a database? The script being dynamic won't depend on wherever it's from.

Answer (score 5):

[eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) will do what you want.

```
eval($string);
```

I really wouldn't suggest storing php in your database though as there are normally much more predictable, readable, understandable and maintainable ways of handling issues where you dynamically run different code based on results.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
<?php eval('?>' . $str . '<?php'); ?>
```

However, eval is not a great way of executing code. I wouldn't suggest storing php code in a database anyways as it makes it very difficult to debug, and it can be insecure, as it could contain malicious code.

Also checkout why lots of people say that 'Eval is Evil':

https://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx?Redirected=true
https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/

Comment: eval() deoesnt work... if condition is stored in that variable